# Broadcast Receiver for multiple database Cursor

Tags: android, cursor, broadcastreceiver

I have been stuck on this problem for a while.

Is there any good example for Broadcast Receiver with multiple database Cursor?

PROBLEM:
I have implemented PagerTabStrip, and also BroadCast receiver and notification for reminder.

So when I click on notification on device screen, it only opens the first cursor, it doesnt open the other too.. I am pretty sure that, I have closed my cursors.

THIS IS JUST OPENS UP THE BLANK ACTIVITY without and STUFF I WANT.

```
public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService{

public ReminderService(){
    super("ReminderService");
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void doReminderWork(Intent intent){
    Log.d("ReminderService", "Doing work.");
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(TaskDatabase.KEY_ROWID);

    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, TaskEdit.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(TaskDatabase.KEY_ROWID, rowId);

    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

/// Rest of the COde.

BROADCASTRECEIVER(this class gets the cursor)

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    ReminderManager reminderMgr = new ReminderManager(context);

    TaskDatabase dbHelper = new TaskDatabase(context);
    dbHelper.open();
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllGeneralRemindersByDefault();
    if(cursor != null){

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int rowIdColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskDatabase.KEY_ROWID);
        int dateTimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskDatabase.KEY_DATE_TIME);

        while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false){
            Log.d(TAG, "Adding alarm from boot.");
            Log.d(TAG, "Row Id Column Index - " + rowIdColumnIndex);
            Log.d(TAG, "Date Time Column Index - " + dateTimeColumnIndex);

            Long rowId = cursor.getLong(rowIdColumnIndex);
            String dateTime = cursor.getString(dateTimeColumnIndex);

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(TaskEdit.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
            try{
                java.util.Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
                cal.setTime(date);

                reminderMgr.setReminder(rowId, cal);
            }catch(java.text.ParseException e){
                Log.e("OnBootReceiver", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
```

Comment: can you show the code that handles the notification click?

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: Still not clear to me. In your code there is only one cursor? Any LogCat output? also I think there is a getColumnIndexOrThrow method (nice if you made changes to the database and forgot to update it or reinstall the app)

Comment: I have reinstalled the app many times, Do you think its a problem with getCOlumnIndexOrThrow method??

Comment: (full uninstall/install?) It just seemed likely that you may have altered the database structure and forgot about it. Then the new column does not exist unless db is recreated from scratch or upgrade is called on db. Where exactly does your code fail?

Comment: yes, I have fully uninstalled and installed the app, It says CursorIndexOutOfBound with value of 0 .. I am pretty sure values are being added to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the understanding of your question in place, I am pretty certain there is a fault in fetchAllGeneralRemindersByDefault(). It is returning en empty cursor. If this is because of the code, or the database being empty, I cannot tell.

Suggestion to code refactor:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
ReminderManager reminderMgr = new ReminderManager(context);

TaskDatabase dbHelper = new TaskDatabase(context);
dbHelper.open();
// returns an empty cursor at index -1 (that is normal behaviour for cursors)
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllGeneralRemindersByDefault();
if(cursor != null && cursor.size() > 0){ // added check 

    int rowIdColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskDatabase.KEY_ROWID);
    int dateTimeColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskDatabase.KEY_DATE_TIME);

    // when you called moveToNext on the empty cursor
    // it corresponds to calling list.get(0) on an empty ArrayList
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        Log.d(TAG, "Adding alarm from boot.");
        Log.d(TAG, "Row Id Column Index - " + rowIdColumnIndex);
        Log.d(TAG, "Date Time Column Index - " + dateTimeColumnIndex);

        Long rowId = cursor.getLong(rowIdColumnIndex);
        String dateTime = cursor.getString(dateTimeColumnIndex);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(TaskEdit.DATE_TIME_FORMAT);
        try{
            java.util.Date date = format.parse(dateTime);
            cal.setTime(date);

            reminderMgr.setReminder(rowId, cal);
        }catch(java.text.ParseException e){
            Log.e("OnBootReceiver", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
} else {
    Log.e("OnBootReceiver", "fetchAllGeneralRemindersByDefault() returned empty cursor");
}
}
```

Comment: hey man, I finally figured it out, it wasn't error in database. Whatever code I had worked perfect, I just passed value through Intent and it worked. This problem was complicated, I couldn't have explained any better than what I did. But thank you for your effort and time. Thank you